# How to hide/show application from launcher using USSD code?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

I want to hide my application in android on button click and unhide it by dialling a particular number.
For example:
  `if I dial 12345 then application unhide from the launcher`.

Comment: What have you tried yet? Write a broadcast receiver to get the outgoing call for your secret code and on receiver show the visibility of application icon. Try with this way if you face any issue I will share code.

Comment: Thanks man its really helps